# how to set resolution of tv at boot/startup

Tags: kde, display-resolution, reboot, tv

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE. This computer is hooked up to a Westinghouse TV, and I had to manually add the resolution of the TV in my .bashrc because it couldn't detect it for some reason:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-0 1920x1080_60.00
```

After adding it to .bashrc it became available in the Display Settings in KDE. However, when I have to restart, it defaults to a very low resolution like 640x480 or 1024x768. How can I set it to automatically use the 1920x1080_60.00 one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I finally figured out a way to get it to work. I added this to the end of my .bashrc file:

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00 --rate 60
```

The login screen is still 640x480, but after I login it changes to 1920x1080.